# When should the first servicing be done for honda activa 5g?

Tags: service

I have purchased my activa 2 weeks back. I wanted to know when the first servicing should be done. Any other maintenance tips would be most welcome.

Comment: If you go [here](https://www.honda2wheelersindia.com/FAQ/BrowseByProduct/2/26) and click on "Free Service Schedule" it will show you the Kms/Days when the first service is due.

Comment: Also, the first place to check for any required maintenance activities is the owner's manual. It should have a schedule for all of these things.

Comment: Usually (good) sales persons make sure the buyer gets all that info... Do cars still have printed manuals? Or are they now downloaded to the smartphone via bluetooth after downloading the manufacturer's app and entering the vin and, of course, credit card info...